# How can I fix this switch statement error?

Tags: swift, xcode, switch-statement

I' having an error saying "switch must be exhaustive 1. Do you want to add missing cases?"

```
func checkAuthorization() {
    switch PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() {
    case .notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self] status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                self?.initPhotoLibrary()
            default:
                self?.handleDeniedAlbumsAuthorization()
            }
        }
    case .authorized:
        self.initPhotoLibrary()
    case .restricted: fallthrough
    case .denied:
        handleDeniedAlbumsAuthorization()
    
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing some switch cases. either define all cases or and default case

Comment: Add `default: break` https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID127

Comment: `Do you want to add missing cases?` -  yes you absolutely do. And Xcode even does it for you, if you don't want to have a `default` case.

Comment: @Gereon Not true, the `@unknown default` is essential.

Comment: @matt but that's what Xcode adds when you click the fix-it, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 14 the correct way to write this is:

```
        case .notDetermined: // ...
        case .restricted: // ...
        case .denied: // ...
        case .authorized: // ...
        case .limited: // ...
        @unknown default: // ...
```

Comment: Hello matt! Someone else programmed this app for me, I'm really an entrepreneur who knows a little about code and I need to fix this one error.

Comment: Do i need to rewrite the code? Or can I just fix it the way it is?

Comment: What you put in the cases is up to you. But they must all be present and they must all contain some code.